# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'CSRF attack'

Tags: php

Доброй ночи, есть вот такой код в файле login.php:

```
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' ) {
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'csrf' ] ) || $_SESSION[ 'csrf' ] !== $_POST[ 'csrf' ] )
        throw new RuntimeException( 'CSRF attack' );
}
$key                = sha1( microtime() );
$_SESSION[ 'csrf' ] = $key;
```

Из-за этого кода генерируется в логах такая ошибка:

**PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'CSRF attack' in /var/www/login.php:26\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/login.php on line 26, referer: www.travianx5.ru/login.php**

Можете объяснить, что делает приведенный выше код? И как мне избавиться от этой ошибки?

Comment: во все формы добавьте поле с "csrf" и запишите туда из сессии $_SESSION[ 'csrf' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенный выше код как раз и вызывает ошибку. 
У вас в условии написано "Если нет сессии csrf, или сессия csrf не равна POST от csrf, тогда вызываем ошибку RuntimeException с сообщением 'CSRF attack'"

А потом в сессию записывается ключ, который, наверняка, не равен POST-у от csrf.
Вот этот условие и срабатывает.

Чтоб избавиться, необходимо стереть нафиг все это:

```
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' ) {
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'csrf' ] ) || $_SESSION[ 'csrf' ] !== $_POST[ 'csrf' ] )
        throw new RuntimeException( 'CSRF attack' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это защита от [CSRF-атак](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2), которая блокирует запрос, если в нем не содержится верного CSRF-значения (здесь это просто хэш от времени), что позволяет защититься от специфичного вида автоматизированных запросов. CSRF-защита проставляется одновременно в форму и в сессию, и действие производится только в том случае, если значения из пришедшей формы и сессии совпадут. У вас, очевидно, либо форма не включает в себя CSRF, либо вы каким-то образом не все данные послали.

Для избавления есть два пути: разобраться, что выдает форма (и убедиться, что в форме содержится то же самое, что и в сессии), или вырезать к чертям весь кусок кода. Защиту в виде хэша по времени я надежной бы не назвал, просто увеличивает сложность (пусть даже и подгадать надо с точностью до микросекунды), этакий псевдо-ГСПЧ. Хотя все равно лучше, чем ничего.